# Why can blood vessel contraction be described as a second order system?

Tags: mathematical-models, blood-pressure

[image]

Suppose that the x-axis represents time, and the y-axis vessel diameter.

Then this graph is claimed to roughly describe what happens when the blood pressure increases, then decreases.

When the blood pressure first increases, the vessel diameter expands to its maximum radius. Then it contracts. What I don't understand is why it keeps on expanding and contracting after its initial expansion - does this model still make sense after its initial expansion and contraction?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: This phenomenon is called damped oscillation. Negative feedbacks sometimes result in such kinds of dynamics. I don't know the physiological mechanism behind it if there is one but I can understand the logic.

Comment: In broad terms: pressure causes vessel to dilate, which in turn reduces the pressure, which in turn reduces the diameter, which then leads to increase in pressure. With certain sets of parameters you would get damped oscillation. Can you provide a reference to the model that you mention?

Comment: the blood vessels have smooth muscle cells on its walls. One of the property of the smooth muscle cell is that it contracts when stretched. I think this explains the physiology behind damped oscillation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many systems have this property. The plot you are looking at is the plot of the [transfer function](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3961098/) for blood vessel diameter vs time. A trick in mathematics or engineering is to understand a system is to sometimes look at at different system with the same properties that you do understand. For instance, a mass springer damper system is similar to a RLC circuit. That is, if we understand the mass spring damper system, we view the RLC circuit as the analog to the mechanical system and vice versa. In the case of blood pressure, we also have a driven force (the heart). Thus, an extremely simple model would be
$$
m\ddot{x} + c\dot{x} + kx = F(t)
$$
As we see below, the mass spring damper model produces the a similar plot of the transfer function. If you understand the mechanical system or RLC circuit, you can look at your plot parameters as an analog to one of these systems to understand the dynamics occurring in the body.

[image]

A more interesting question is can we use [PID control](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlPID) to manage the overshoot, rise time, and settling time of the vessel diameter in the body?

---

The differential equation that models this process is probably related to a Bernoulli differential equation.

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle
2. page 15 http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~jbryant/Fluids/Fluidslect4.pdf
3. http://bme.ccny.cuny.edu/faculty/bfu/blood%20flow%20permeability%20in%20microvessels.pdf

A precise differential equation will need to account for pressure (Bernoulli), fluids (Navier-Stokes), and the elasticity of the vessel walls.